# Control/limit requestAnimationFrame FPS

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, fps

Is there a way to limit/cap requestAnimationFrame FPS in Chromium browsers? I want to cap it to 60 fps and **have each frame lasting exactly 1/60 second**. It seems that `--limit-fps` flag used to exist, but it's not working at least for newer versions.

Please notice that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764018/controlling-fps-with-requestanimationframe) doesn't help me, because by doing these workarounds you won't have frames distributed evenly per time window if you have a monitor with 75 Hz refresh rate, for instance.